# Getting url for all zip files from webpage

Tags: beautifulsoup, python-3.8

I am looking at the [webpage](https://www.ercot.com/misapp/GetReports.do?reportTypeId=12331&reportTitle=DAM%20Settlement%20Point%20Prices&showHTMLView=&mimicKey) with bunch of zip files in them.

Each of zip file has url as `https://www.ercot.com/misdownload/servlets/mirDownload?mimic_duns=000000000&doclookupId=814778337`

I want to extract the urls for only `_csv.zip` files and extract the files into a csv file and discard urls for `_xml.zip` files. Both the `xml.zip` and `csv.zip` has the same data but I prefer to use the `csv.zip`.

I am not sure how to approach this or where to start.

**Edit:**

If you are getting "Access Denied", please note that the webpage might be only accessible to USA IP addresses.

When you click on the urls, it downloads a zip file to PC. I basically want to:

1. download the zip file to the PC
2. load the contents of the csv file inside the zip to a pandas dataframe

Comment: That webpage leads to an "Access Denied" page. A better [mcve] would be providing sample inputs. Is it an HTML page that you need to parse? What does the HTML structure look like? Or is it a list of strings? Or is it the response from an API? What does a URL with a `_csv.zip` file look like? And what does "*extract the files into a csv file*" mean? What is the expected format/content of the CSV file? I understand you put a bounty on this, but the goal is not clear. Showing what you tried could clear up what needs to be done and what went wrong with your attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the zip files and a merged csv file (21 MB) are [here](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/YLWGKGjexOhTyw), so no need for scraping.

But if you feel like it, here's my take on it.

```py
import os.path
from shutil import copyfileobj

import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = "https://www.ercot.com"
entry_url = f"{base_url}/misapp/GetReports.do?reportTypeId=12331&reportTitle=DAM%20Settlement%20Point%20Prices&showHTMLView=&mimicKey"
download_dir = "ercot"


def scrape_zips():
    with requests.Session() as connection:
        print("Finding all zip files...")
        zip_urls = [
            f"{base_url}{source_url['href']}" for source_url in
            BeautifulSoup(
                connection.get(entry_url).text,
                "lxml"
            ).find_all("a")[::2]
        ]

        os.makedirs(download_dir, exist_ok=True)
        total_urls = len(zip_urls)
        for idx, url in enumerate(zip_urls, start=1):
            file_name = url.split("=", -1)[-1]
            zip_object = connection.get(url, stream=True)
            print(f"Fetching file {file_name} -> {idx} out of {total_urls}")
            with open(os.path.join(download_dir, f"{file_name}.zip"), "wb") as output:
                copyfileobj(zip_object.raw, output)
            zip_object.close()


def list_files(dir_name: str):
    yield from (
        next(os.walk(dir_name), (None, None, []))[2]
    )


def merge_zips_to_df():
    print("Merging csv files...")
    df = pd.concat(
        pd.read_csv(os.path.join(download_dir, csv_file)) for csv_file
        in list_files(download_dir)
    )
    print(df.head(20))
    df.to_csv(os.path.join(download_dir, "merdged_csv_files.csv"), index=False)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    scrape_zips()
    merge_zips_to_df()
```

This should give you the following output:

```
Finding all zip files...
Fetching file 816055622 -> 1 out of 31
Fetching file 815870449 -> 2 out of 31
Fetching file 815686938 -> 3 out of 31
Fetching file 815503551 -> 4 out of 31
Fetching file 815315296 -> 5 out of 31
Fetching file 815127892 -> 6 out of 31
Fetching file 814952388 -> 7 out of 31
Fetching file 814778337 -> 8 out of 31
Fetching file 814599101 -> 9 out of 31
Fetching file 814416972 -> 10 out of 31
Fetching file 814224618 -> 11 out of 31
Fetching file 814040277 -> 12 out of 31
Fetching file 813865857 -> 13 out of 31
Fetching file 813688802 -> 14 out of 31
Fetching file 813516414 -> 15 out of 31
Fetching file 813341752 -> 16 out of 31
Fetching file 813159478 -> 17 out of 31
Fetching file 812976112 -> 18 out of 31
Fetching file 812784659 -> 19 out of 31
Fetching file 812599985 -> 20 out of 31
Fetching file 812424952 -> 21 out of 31
Fetching file 812241625 -> 22 out of 31
Fetching file 812053445 -> 23 out of 31
Fetching file 811874015 -> 24 out of 31
Fetching file 811685701 -> 25 out of 31
Fetching file 811501577 -> 26 out of 31
Fetching file 811319918 -> 27 out of 31
Fetching file 811147926 -> 28 out of 31
Fetching file 810973966 -> 29 out of 31
Fetching file 810793357 -> 30 out of 31
Fetching file 810615891 -> 31 out of 31
Merging csv files...
   DeliveryDate HourEnding SettlementPoint  SettlementPointPrice DSTFlag
0    12/22/2021      01:00            AEEC                 25.07       N
1    12/22/2021      01:00     AJAXWIND_RN                 25.07       N
2    12/22/2021      01:00    ALGOD_ALL_RN                 25.01       N
3    12/22/2021      01:00        ALVIN_RN                 24.11       N
4    12/22/2021      01:00     AMADEUS_ALL                 25.07       N
5    12/22/2021      01:00     AMISTAD_ALL                 25.06       N
6    12/22/2021      01:00    AMOCOOIL_CC1                 25.98       N
7    12/22/2021      01:00    AMOCOOIL_CC2                 25.98       N
8    12/22/2021      01:00      AMOCO_PUN1                 25.98       N
9    12/22/2021      01:00      AMOCO_PUN2                 25.98       N
10   12/22/2021      01:00     AMO_AMOCO_1                 25.98       N
11   12/22/2021      01:00     AMO_AMOCO_2                 25.98       N
12   12/22/2021      01:00     AMO_AMOCO_5                 25.98       N
13   12/22/2021      01:00    AMO_AMOCO_G1                 25.98       N
14   12/22/2021      01:00    AMO_AMOCO_G2                 25.98       N
15   12/22/2021      01:00    AMO_AMOCO_G3                 25.98       N
16   12/22/2021      01:00    AMO_AMOCO_S1                 25.98       N
17   12/22/2021      01:00    AMO_AMOCO_S2                 25.98       N
18   12/22/2021      01:00    ANACACHO_ANA                 25.05       N
19   12/22/2021      01:00      ANCHOR_ALL                 25.08       N
```